# MySQL Query that works fine through SQL pro not working in mysqli_query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I tried many things but can't understand why this is not working...
Basically, I am dropping and creating tables. The following query works perfect in SQL PRO, or mysqladmin

```
SET foreign_key_checks = 0;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `calendarCountries`;

CREATE TABLE `calendarCountries` (
  `id` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `country` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

insert into calendarCountries (id,country) values (1,'US');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `calendarWorldHolidays`;

CREATE TABLE `calendarWorldHolidays` (
  `holidayName` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `holidayDate` date NOT NULL,
  `countryCode` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `countryCode` (`countryCode`),
  CONSTRAINT `calendarWorldHolidays_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`countryCode`) REFERENCES `calendarCountries` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

SET foreign_key_checks = 1;
```

But whenever I try to execute it through php it is not working, giving me a syntax error.

I just copy past the sql statements to php like so

```
$createTablesQuery = "  <I copy the statements above here>   "
mysqli_query($link, $createTablesQuery)
```

THe error I get is:

> Invalid query: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `calendarCountries`; CREATE TABLE `calendarCountries` ( ' at line 3

Please help me, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can't execute multiple queries like that. Use `mysqli_multi_query()` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [mysqli_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) function allows to use only one query. If you need to run a few queries, you need either use one `mysqli_query` per query or use the [mysqli_multi_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php) function. For example:

```
$query1 = "CREATE TABLE `calendarCountries` ( `id` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `country` varchar(50) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;";
$query2 = "insert into calendarCountries (id,country) values (1,'US');";

//Variant 1
mysqli_query($link, $query1);
mysqli_query($link, $query2);

//Variant2
mysqli_multi_query($link, $query1.$query2);
```